# How to detect if a tab of a given tabid exists?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I tried to use `chrome.tabs.get` to detect if the tab corresponds to a tabid exists:

```
chrome.tabs.get tabid, (tab) ->
  if tab?
    chrome.tabs.update tabid, selected: yes
    # window.close()
  else
    url = q('#choose').querySelector('.url').innerText
    options =
      url: url
      active: yes
    chrome.tabs.create options
    # window.close()
```

The code works but it gives error like this:

```
tabs.get: No tab with id: 107.
  at gotoTab (chrome-extension://lldkaekdbdcgilnmbheemjooggcnhopl/lib/find.js:150:22)
```

It is quite strange I can get tabids by search tabs and bookmarks and history, but the tab just don't exist. Is there a better way to detect the existance of a tabid?

Comment: How did you get the tabId? Not all `tabId`s map to a visible tab. For instance, if you listen to `chrome.webNavigation` events, you will also get notified of pre-rendered tabs.

Comment: I got `tabid` by searching bookmarks and history. I thought is was strange but can't figure out why.

Comment: But these APIs ([`chrome.bookmarks`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks.html) and [`chrome.history`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history.html)) do not supply tabIDs at all.

Comment: @RobW But I did get ids from them.

Comment: The IDs from the bookmark API identify bookmarks, *not* tabs. Similar for the history API. If you still don't get it, would a vending machine in Europe accept dollars, when it says "coins only"? No, because it only recognizes Euros.

Comment: Then is there anyway to tell from each other before I get a tab?

Comment: I didn't get your last question. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: when there is no tab, `chrome.tabs.get tabid, (tab) ->` assigns `undefined` to `tab`, gives an error in the meanwhile, but didn't block the callback function. So I want to avoid that error. So I think if there's a right way to do so.

Comment: Not "right", but you can override the console.error method and filter the method.